# Programmatically add quick launch link to a modal dialog box

Tags: 2010, development, quick-launch

I have implemented a feature that once activated adds a heading called Home, and a link underneath to a `NewForm.aspx` like such:

```
// Add Home node
var mainListsNode = new SPNavigationNode("Home", web.Url, true);
leftNav.AddAsFirst(mainListsNode);

// Add NewForm link
node = new SPNavigationNode("Add New Item", string.Format("{0}/Lists/CustomList/NewForm.aspx", web.Url), true);
homeNode.Children.AddAsLast(node);
```

My requirement is now to make that link pop open the modal dialog box instead. I achieved this easily in my webpart where I can use JavaScript like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:openDialog();return false;" target="_self">

function openDialog() {
    var options = {
        url: '/sites/TESTSITE/Lists/CustomList/NewForm.aspx?IsDlg=1',
        title: "Add New Item",
        dialogReturnValueCallback: itemNotificationSent,
        allowMaximize: false
    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

How can I achieve this in my first example? Bonus points for advising me how I can also add my `dialogReturnValueCallback` as my second example:

```
function itemNotificationSent(dialogResult, returnValue) {
    if (dialogResult == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
        SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('An Item was added. Thank you!');
    }

    else {
        SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('The "Item Add" was cancelled...');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, sharepoint uses `AspMenu` as control that renders top nav and quick lunch. Something interesting you can find using reflector in this control. Consider method `OnMenuItemDataBound` (some code omitted for clarity):

```
if (bool.TryParse(dataItem["AllowScriptUrl"], out result) && result)
{
    if (this.allowScriptUrlItems == null)
    {
        this.allowScriptUrlItems = new Dictionary<MenuItem, bool>();
    }
    this.allowScriptUrlItems.Add(e.Item, true);
}
```

where dataItem is a SiteMapNode object. And another peace of code, from `BuildDefaultInnerItem` method:

```
if (((item != null) && item.Enabled) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(navigateUrl) || item.Selectable))
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(navigateUrl))
    {
        if (navigateUrl.StartsWith("javascript:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (this.allowScriptUrls || ((this.allowScriptUrlItems != null) && this.allowScriptUrlItems.ContainsKey(item)))
            {
                writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, navigateUrl, false);
            }
        }
```

[SPNavigationNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigationnode_members.aspx) class has `Properties`, that mapped to dataItem. Hmmm, it seems that this code should work:

```
var leftNav = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
var mainListsNode = new SPNavigationNode("jslink", "javascript:alert('hi there!')", true);
leftNav.AddAsFirst(mainListsNode);
mainListsNode.Properties["AllowScriptUrl"] = "true";
mainListsNode.Update();
```

..and it actually works! This code produces this html markup:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('hi there!')" class="static menu-item">
    <span class="additional-background">
       <span class="menu-item-text">jslink</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

So, you can put your javascript on masterpage, and call required functions using above technique.
For example, something like this:

```
var leftNav = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
var mainListsNode = new SPNavigationNode("jslink", "javascript:mycoolfunc('" + web.Title + "')", true);
leftNav.AddAsFirst(mainListsNode);
mainListsNode.Properties["AllowScriptUrl"] = "true";
mainListsNode.Update();
```

and js:

```
function mycoolfunc(param){
    alert(param);
    }
```

**note**: you should always call SPNavigationNode constuctor with 3 arguments and `true` as 3rd, failing that you got an exception (The specified url does not exist in the site collection...).

**UPDATE**

My experiments revealed that this lines are redundant

```
mainListsNode.Properties["AllowScriptUrl"] = "true";
mainListsNode.Update();
```

you need only specify js function and mark that this external link, and that's it. I mistakenly thought that correlation exists between  `SPNavigationNode` properties and `dataItem`.

Comment: Dear Kai, that worked. I had a feeling it was the Properties that need to be set but couldn't find any site explaining what properties there are.

Comment: Please, refer to my update, I found that some lines are redundant.